# Is it possible to shorten bulk code

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a lot of code for 1 Button. Are there any ways to shorten this code.

```
      pic1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {              
 public void onClick(View v) {            
      pic1.setTag("beck");      
 if  (pic2.getTag()==("beck")){            
  new CountDownTimer(500,500) {  
  public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}
  public void onFinish() {
     player=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.correct);
     player.start();
     pic1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     pic2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);                        
     }}.start();            
     }
 if (pic1.getTag()==("beck")){pic1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.becks);}    
 if (pic3.getTag()==("rob") || pic4.getTag()==("rob")
   ||pic5.getTag()==("shan") || pic6.getTag()==("shan")
   ||pic7.getTag()==("mel") || pic8.getTag()==("mel")
   ||pic9.getTag()==("dumm") || pic10.getTag()==("dumm")
   ||pic11.getTag()==("jboot") || pic12.getTag()==("jboot")  ) {
     pic1.setTag ("boot");pic1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots);
     pic2.setTag ("boot");pic2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots);
     pic3.setTag ("boot");pic3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots);
     pic4.setTag ("boot");pic4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots); 
     pic5.setTag ("boot");pic5.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots);
     pic6.setTag ("boot");pic6.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots);
     pic7.setTag ("boot");pic7.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots); 
     pic8.setTag ("boot");pic8.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots);
     pic9.setTag ("boot");pic9.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots);
     pic10.setTag ("boot");pic10.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots); 
     pic11.setTag ("boot");pic11.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots); 
     pic12.setTag ("boot");pic12.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots);  }    

     }});
```

For example creating a second class to hold the code so i can call it when needed. or methods such as

```
pic1,pic2,pic3.setTag("boot")
```

Ive created a second class and put the Tag and Background reset into it.

```
public class resetbuttons extends MainActivity{
public void buttreset () {
 pic1.setTag("boot");
 pic1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots); 
 pic2.setTag("boot");
 pic2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots);
 // etc etc for 12 buttons      }}
```

And in place of the if statements Tag and image code ive put this.

```
resetbuttons parent = new resetbuttons();
parent.buttreset();
```

all the code looks clean but when i run it as soon as the buttreset is called the app crashes. Do i need to add anything to the manifest or xml code. If not where is my error. This is the main code i want to get rid off in my main activity

Comment: arrays... Google it. :D

Comment: How are you comparing Strings?!

Comment: Note : Don't use `==` to compare the content of `Strings` in Java. Use `equals()`

Comment: All of the above and loops

Comment: put beck,rob... in a list to be able to do something like if(oList.contains(pic.getTag()))... use array of pic's and use loops for setting pic's tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for starters, you can replace this:

```
 pic1.setTag ("boot");pic1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots);
 pic2.setTag ("boot");pic2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots);
 pic3.setTag ("boot");pic3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots);
 pic4.setTag ("boot");pic4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots); 
 pic5.setTag ("boot");pic5.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots);
 pic6.setTag ("boot");pic6.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots);
 pic7.setTag ("boot");pic7.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots); 
 pic8.setTag ("boot");pic8.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots);
 pic9.setTag ("boot");pic9.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots);
 pic10.setTag ("boot");pic10.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots); 
 pic11.setTag ("boot");pic11.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots); 
 pic12.setTag ("boot");pic12.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots);
```

with this

```
for (int i = 0;i < pic.length;i++)
    {
    pic[i].setTag("boot");
    pic[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots);
    }
```

but to do this, **you need to make the pic variables into an array properly.** I don't know what class they are, nor how many you need, so I can't tell you how to declare the array. All I can say is this:

```
*NAME OF CLASS*[] pic = new *NAME OF CLASS* [*NUMBER OF THINGS*]();
```

Also, be sure to initialize the array. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Use arrays/collections with `for-loop` to do the same action again and again:

```
View[] views = {pic1, pic2, pic3, pic4, pic5, pic6, pic7, pic8, pic9, pic10, pic11, pic12};

for(View v : views){
    v.setTag("boot");
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots);
}
```

Also, you need to change all `==` to `equals()` if you want to compare `String` object.

Comment: ive done what youve said it works to a point except any button clicked makes all images change to R.drawable.jordboots

Comment: This snippet is to replace `pic1.setTag("boot");pic1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots);pic2.setTag ("boot");pic2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots);...` only. If you have more questions, edit and add it on your post.

Comment: Is there a way to reset all the Button Tags at once such as Tags. reset();

Comment: What did you mean by "reset"? You can set the tag to `null`, but if you want to do it again and again, consider using the same loop, or make a helper method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for example `Guava`'s `ImmutableList` and put there the Strings which are "allowed":

```
private static final ImmutableList<String> listOfAllowedStrings = 
    ImmutableList<String>.of("beck", "rob", "shan"); //...etc.
```

Then running through every pic simply check if that value is in that list:

```
if(listOfAllowedStrings.contains(picX.getTag())) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sets are more efficient than lists to test `contains`

Comment: @njzk2 Yes, they are. I used List "*for example*", as I think it's the easiest data structure. Anyway, good point to add.

Comment: Out of curiosity, `Collections` already containing `Arrays.asList(T ...)` which returns an immutable list, what is the benefit of Guava here?

Comment: It has the `of()` method, so one doesn't need to create an array before ;-)

Comment: IMHO, I still cannot suggest to use `Collection`'s `contains()` to check `picX.getTag()` without more detail about the requirement. This code will fail if `pic3.getTag()` returns `"shan"` (or other in the collections)... otherwise, it's a good optimization.

Comment: @EelLee : but the asList takes a `...` argument so there is no need for an array either

Comment: @EelLee : Being curious I read a bit more about the specifics of ImmutableList. Apparently it copies the input to make an actually immutable list, while Arrays directly uses the input array as the content of the list, making it possible to change the underlying data.